# select subquery inside then of case when statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery, case

Is there a way to run a select statement from a "then" in the sql server case/when statement? (I need to run subqueries from a then statement.)  I cannot have it in the where statement.

```
select 
  case @Group 
    when 6500 then (select top 10 * from Table1)
    when 5450 then (select top 5 * from Table1)
    when 2010 then (select top 3 * from Table1)
    when 2000 then (select top 1 * from Table1)
    else 0 
  end as 'Report'
```

Comment: You want to return 10 rows, or 5 rows, or 3 rows etc. inside a single column value? Not sure I follow.

Comment: Those are just examples of what I need to do....the real queries are much longer and are not top anythings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to remove this from the query and do something like:

```
declare @Numrows int;
select @Numrows = (case @Group 
                        when 6500 then  10
                        when 5450 then 5
                        when 2010 then 3
                        when 2000 then 1
                        else 0
                   end);

select top(@NumRows) *
from Table1;
```

You could also do it this way:

```
with const as (
      select (case @Group 
                        when 6500 then  10
                        when 5450 then 5
                        when 2010 then 3
                        when 2000 then 1
                        else 0
                   end) as Numrows
    )
select t.*
from (select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over () as seqnum
      from table1 t 
     ) t cross join
     const
where seqnum <= NumRows;
```

In this case, you need to list out the columns to avoid getting `seqnum` in the list.

By the way, normally when using `top` you should also have `order by`.  Otherwise, the results are indeterminate.

Comment: well, the subqueries are just examples of having to run a query inside a "then" statement. The actual queries I am going to run have columns and sums and whole bunch of other stuff.

Comment: @PerryDay . . . Well, you can't do it with a single SQL statement.

Comment: I downvoted by mistake. Now I can't remove it. Can you edit so I can remove the downvote? Sorry

Comment: @vpascoal . . . Thanks.  I've become rather sensitive to anonymous downvotes (both on my posts and on other people's posts).

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a SELECT within a SELECT. You can use IF...ELSE though e.g.

```
IF @Group = 6500
    select top 10* from Table1 AS Report
ELSE IF @Group = 5450
    select top 5* from Table1 AS Report
ELSE IF @Group = 2010
    select top 3* from Table1 AS Report
ELSE IF @Group = 2000
    select top 1* from Table1 AS Report
```

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon has the answer already. This is just second opnion. You can use dynamic query.

```
declare @query varchar(max)
declare @Group int
set @query = ''

if @Group = 6500 
  set @query = 'select top 10 * from table1'
if @Group = 5450 
  set @query = 'select top 5 * from table1'
if @Group = 2010 
  set @query = 'select top 3 * from table1'
if @Group = 2000 
  set @query = 'select top 1 * from table1'

exec(@query)
```

Comment: this compiles without error, but it doesn't show the results of the query. I need it to show the results.

Comment: You need to give the Group variable value, like Set @Group = 6500, or else, query will be empty.